# Scaling font headings with flexible grid

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design

I have percentage based column and gutter widths in the scenario pictured below. I would like the (text) column headings to also scale in size if viewed on a different device or browser width, as they would if they were 100% width images.

I had a quick look at the FitText jQuery extension which scales text to fit the containing element, but in my case below, that would involve putting the headings in three custom containers, tweaked to ensure font heights are consistent.

I also don't wish to rely on JavaScript.

Is there an easy way, or should I just bite the bullet and use images?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use images for text * *shudder* *.

You can either use [fit-text](http://fittextjs.com/), or [slab text](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/) (both do the same thing).

If you're looking for a solution that doesn't require JS then you're going to have to look at adding some additional breakpoints to make the text change as it begins to look bad.  You an also add some transition effects on that to make it a little smoother.